# HTML-Different ul styles in the same code (Mustn't n'use any links)

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a text that has twor unordered lists.
The fist needs to have tickmars, while the second just bullets.
The text is supposed to be sent via email so I must not use any css links as I am not sure that the recipients have access to them.

I need to create two lists one with tickmarks and one with bullet.

So, now I want another list that is has bullets. 
How can I do that?

I want two lists, one with tickmarks and one with bullets

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use css links, you could include your css inside html with style tag:

```
.custom-ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.custom-ul > li:before {
   content: '\2714\0020';
   margin-left: -1em;
}
```

Then apply class .custom-ul to your first list. You can try tickmarks with codes \2713, \2714, \2611.
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JVWPMg)